# Лабораторная по Delphi - укажите на ошибки

Tags: delphi

Работа заключается в том чтобы программа при вводе вершин треугольника и точки говорила находится ли точка в треугольнике или нет.
Вот сижу ломаю голову,  в строке Var вроде всё прописал.
[[image: Фото скриншота с ошибкой и кодом][1]]

```
      Program Lab2consol ;
Var X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X4,Y4,S,S1,S2,S3,p,p1,p2,p3,a,b,c,k,l,t : Real;
Begin
Write ('X1 ,Y1, X2, Y2 ,X3 ,Y3 ,X4 ,Y4 ,S ,S1 ,S2, S3 ,p ,p1 ,p2 ,p3 ,a ,b ,c ,k ,l ,t');
Readln(X1 ,Y1 ,X2 ,Y2 ,X3 ,Y3 ,X4 ,Y4 ,S ,S1, S2, S3, p ,p1 ,p2 ,p3 ,a, b ,c ,k, l, t );

 a := sqrt((X3-X1)^2 + (Y3-Y1)^2)
 b := sqrt((X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2)
 c := sqrt((X3-X2)^2 + (Y3-Y2)^2)
 k := sqrt((X4-X1)^2 + (Y4-Y1)^2)
 l := sqrt((X4-X2)^2 + (Y4-Y2)^2)
 t := sqrt((X4-X3)^2 = (Y4-Y3)^2)
 p := (a+b+c)/2
 S :=sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))
 p1 := (b+k+l)/2
 p2 := (a+k+t)/2
 p3 := (c+l+t)/2
 S1 :=sqrt(p*(p-b)*(p-l)*(p-k)
 S2 :=sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-k)*(p-t)
 S3 :=sqrt(p*(p-c)*(p-l)*(p-t)
 Begin
   If S = S1 + S2 +S3 then
    ShowMessage ('Точка знаходиться в межах трикутника');
    Halt
  end else ;
   Begin
    If S < S1 + S2 +S3 then
    ShowMessage ('Точка знаходиться за межами трикутника');
    Halt
 end else
 begin
   if S > S1 + S2 + S3 then
   Show Messag ('Точка знаходится в межах трикутника') ;
   Halt
 end;
 end;
 End.
```

Comment: Приложите ваш код текстом

Comment: вас там еще не знакомили со структурами данных?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1):

1. в `readln` переменные через запятую указываются
2. после `else` не надо ставить `;`
3. в конструкции `if then else` `begin/end` стоят не на месте

Comment: @Igor, виноват, погорячился

Comment: а в целом отсутствия точек с запятой в строках вы не заметили?